# классы в javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
class Button {
constructor ($element) {
  this.$element = $element;
  this.coords = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
 w: 0,
    h: 0
  }
}
}

Button.prototype.setCoords_but = function(x, y, w, h) {
  this.coords = {
    x: x,
    y: y,
 w: w,
    h: h
  }
   this.$element.offset({
    top: this.coords.x,
    left: this.coords.y
  });
  this.$element.css({height: this.coords.h, width: this.coords.w});
 }



var button_proverka = new Button($('#proverka'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>


  <button id="proverka">Проверка</button>  
  <button id="delete">Очистить</button> 
  <button id="table_ist"  >Построить</button>
  
</body>
```

Вопрос заключается в следующем: возможно ли описать класс в отдельном файле и вызвать его в другом файле? Если возможно такое, то каким образом! и следующее: как можно изменять стиль кнопки при наведении курсора мыши и нажатие на кнопку (все это должно быть описано в классе)

Answer (score 1):

> Возможно ли описать класс в отдельном файле и вызвать его в другом файле?

Да, возможно, при этом файл с классом должен быть подключен раньше файла с его вызовом. Если вы конкатенируете файлы в один, код с классом должен быть в результате выше, т.к. его объявление не всплывает.

> как можно изменять стиль кнопки при наведении курсора мыши и нажатие на кнопку (все это должно быть описано в классе)

Если вы не хотите/не можете делать это через CSS, вешайте на кнопку обработчики событий мыши:

```
class Button {

    constructor($element) {
        this.$element = $element;

        this.$element.addEventListener('mouseover', this.onMouseover);
        this.$element.addEventListener('mouseout', this.onMouseout);
        this.$element.addEventListener('click', this.onClick);
    }

    ...

    onMouseover(event) { /*код функции*/ }

    onMouseout(event) { /*код функции*/ }

    onClick(event) { /*код функции*/ }

   ...
}
```

p.s. Навешивать обработчики не обязательно в конструкторе. Можете поместить их в отдельную функцию и вызвать ее, когда вам будет удобнее.

Comment: все понятно, спасибо за помощь

Comment: @svetlana2694 если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный